# Xamarin: Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, referenced by `MySqlConnector`.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I can't build my Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio 2017.

I keep getting this error:

```
Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, referenced by `MySqlConnector`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove the reference to `MySqlConnector`.
```

System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions is installed with NuGet. I need MySqlConnector.

I already cleaned the solution, cleaned all NuGet files, restarted Visual Studio, restarted my PC, reinstalled that NuGet package, reinstalled all NuGet packages, switched from Debug to Release and back, changed C# version, made sure all file permissions were correct on all NuGet files, referenced the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions as dll, etc.

But the error just stays there. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Here is a aimilar issue that yoy can refer https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1879

Comment: Funny it just compiles in VS 2019 and refuses to do so in VS 2017.

Comment: The underlying issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/ppy/osu/pull/5394). It is still not working in VS 2017, but has been fixed in VS 2019.

Comment: Not working in VS2019 as of 13dec2019

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you are using the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions in the version of 4.5.1 or 4.5.2, you can try to uninstall the 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 and install version 4.5.0 in your Xamarin. Android project.

As of now (14-Jan-2019), It is a workaround before Xamarin solves the root cause of this issue in the newer version.

Comment: is there a bug we can track in the Xamarin bug tracker that we can follow to know when this issue gets fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Dec2019 and installing 4.5.0 results in a "java.exe existed with a code 2" failure to build.

Going to try hand editing the android project file as described here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/134422/could-not-load-assembly-system-threading-tasks-extensions

> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>     <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive" Version="4.1.1" />
>     <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.5.2"/>
>   </ItemGroup>
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
>       <HintPath>$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
>     </Reference>
>   </ItemGroup>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions v4.5.1 nuget package to your Xamarin.Android project.
2. Close Visual Studio.
3. Open your Xamarin.Android *.csproj file with a Text Editor.
4. Add another `<ItemGroup>` to tell your project to use the `.netstandard2.0` profile
   instead of the `MonoAndroid10` profile

```js
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
        <HintPath>$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Save the file and reload your project in visual studio. After I did that I was able to compile successfully.